# Private key length > public key?

Tags: encryption, rsa, private-key, public-key

I'm working on rsa private and public key / encryption / decryption / etc using openssl module. But a question is still unanswered : why private key are often (are always, i don't know) longer than public key ?

Is there several answer to this ?

[image: public and private key]

This is my public and private key generated.

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps you should try [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *RSA* private key includes the values that are in the *RSA* public key, and some more values that are *private*. Futhermore, the values themselves are larger.

The public key contains the modulus and the public exponent *e* which is short (mostly 3 or 65537). On the other hand the private key contains the private exponent *d* ≡ *e*<sup>−1</sup> (mod φ(*n*)). Depending on φ(*n*), *d* can be vastly larger than *e*.

There are other public key algorithms where this is different. Some algorithms based on elliptic curves have a single big integer as the private key (and group description) and the public key has a curve point (and group description) which is larger than the big integer.

Comment: Thank you ! 
Have you any scientific article or other ressources wich can explain to me what are those values ?

Answer (score 4):

> why private key are often (are always, i don't know) longer than public key ?

The answer is detailed in [PKCS 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1) (and friends like [RFC 2437](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2437.txt)).

The public key is the pair `{e, n}`, where `e` is the public exponent and `n` is the modulus.

One of the private key representations is the triplet `{e, d, n}`, where `e` is the public exponent, `d` is the private exponent and `n` is the modulus.

The other private key representations the n-tuple`{e, d, n, p, q, dp, dq, qi}`, where `e` is the public exponent; `d` is the private exponent; `n` is the modulus; and `p` and `q` are the factors of `n`.

And the remaining are for the Chinese Remainder theorem, which allows a speedup in signatures (I believe). `dp` is p's exponent, a positive integer such that `e(dP) ≅ 1 (mod(p-1))`; `dq` is q's exponent, a positive integer such that `e(dq) ≅ 1 (mod(q-1))`; and `qi` is CRT coefficient, a positive integer less than `p` such that `q(qInv) ≅ 1 (mod p)`.